Mule 4 dataweave 2 - how to sort a json object containing other objects
I need to sort a json object ( not an array ) which is not a simple key value
Rather it has additional objects inside it
{
"Memo": {
    "itemAmount1": "5",
    "taxName1": "TAX",
    "productPrice1": "10",
    "accountName1": "Account Receivable (Debtors)"
},
"Footer": {
    "productDescription2": "Maggie",
    "itemQuantity2": "49.5",
    "accountName2": "Account Receivable (Debtors)",
    "taxName2": "TAX"
},
"Header": {
    "itemDiscount3": "10",
    "accountName3": "Account Receivable (Debtors)",
    "productPrice3": "10",
    "taxName3": "TAX"
}
}

Expected output is : ( should sort keys of internal objects as well )
 {
"Footer": {
    "accountName2": "Account Receivable (Debtors)",
    "itemQuantity2": "49.5",
    "productDescription2": "Maggie",
    "taxName2": "TAX"
},
"Header": {
    "accountName3": "Account Receivable (Debtors)",
    "itemDiscount3": "10",
    "productPrice3": "10",
    "taxName3": "TAX"
},
"Memo": {
    "accountName1": "Account Receivable (Debtors)",
    "itemAmount1": "5",
    "productPrice1": "10",
    "taxName1": "TAX"
}
}

It is not necessary that it is 2 level object hierarchy it may contain n level of object hierarchy which need to be sorted.
This question is a virtual copy paste of question asked here ( but thats for javascript not dataweave / mule )

The builtin function orderBy() can sort objects too. But to sort children objects you'll need a recursive function that applies orderBy() to the children matching by type.
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun sortObjects(x)=
    x match {
        case o is Object -> o 
                              orderBy ((value, key) -> key)
                              mapObject (($$): sortObjects($))
        else -> $
  }
---
sortObjects(payload)

Output:
{
  "Footer": {
    "accountName2": "Account Receivable (Debtors)",
    "itemQuantity2": "49.5",
    "productDescription2": "Maggie",
    "taxName2": "TAX"
  },
  "Header": {
    "accountName3": "Account Receivable (Debtors)",
    "itemDiscount3": "10",
    "productPrice3": "10",
    "taxName3": "TAX"
  },
  "Memo": {
    "accountName1": "Account Receivable (Debtors)",
    "itemAmount1": "5",
    "productPrice1": "10",
    "taxName1": "TAX"
  }
}

Note that adding a match to Array you could use the function to also sort arrays at the same time.


Use orderBy and mapObject which will sort the keys as expected.
